# Excel: what is the shortcut key for File -> Export -> Create PDF?

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts

Problem: need to export to PDF many times.

What is the shortcut key for `File -> Export -> Create PDF`?

Is it `Alt + FEA`?

---

UPD: The `Alt + FEA` works. However, is it possible to set up an `Alt + <single_key>`? For example, `Alt + Y` (or any other key).

Comment: Does `Alt + FEA` export as you need? What is your actual problem with that shortcut? Is it that it exports in the wrong format or does nothing at all? Describe your problem in detail. It seems you know what the shortcut might be but you are missing some important information on what your problem actually is.

Comment: @Mokubai Updated.

Comment: You have changed the question. You should really ask a new question "Can I remap the Excel Export to PDF option to a different keybinding?" My answer is based on your original question, but the answer is now invalid as you actually have a different question.

Comment: See also the answer to this question which works for Word, Excel and other office applications. It is really easy to add a button to the Quick Access Toolbar. Don't forget to look for "Publish" to PDF  rather than "Save As". This button does exactly the same as Save As without the need to change the file format every time, and I use it almost every day, sometimes dozens of times.
https://superuser.com/questions/476223/word-2010-one-button-save-as-pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> then <kbd>E</kbd> takes you to the Export options page, where you can choose what to export to.

<kbd>Alt</kbd> then <kbd>E</kbd> then <kbd>A</kbd> will also take you to the `Publish as PDF or XPS` dialog.

If you commonly export to PDF/XPS, consider adding an icon to your Ribbon bar as a shortcut.

Comment: The "new" Office shortcuts do not require you to hold Alt for each key. You can simply tap the keys in order: `Alt` then `F` then `E` then `A` as OPs example would be.

Comment: Noted, and answer update with "classic" and "new" methods.

Comment: You could also do an AutoHotKey script to do this

Comment: Is it possible to set up (in Excel) an `Alt + <single_key>`?